# Footer Repeats Itself

Tags: php, html, repeat

I'm designing [this website](http://www.daytaro.com/Aqua/index.php) and I need it to be .php to communicate with a database and start some countdown clocks (which aren't up yet).  The page was originally .html and everything was perfect, but since I changed it to .php for some reason the footer keeps repeating itself.  The code will be fine on my editor, I'll load the page, reload the file on the editor and the code somehow appears there all on its own!
Right now there is no PHP code whatsoever, I merely changed the file's extension.  If you visit the same URL but the .html version, you'll see everything is fine.  What could be causing this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

Entire HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Aqua</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,900,300italic" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/5grid/init.js?use=mobile,desktop,1000px&amp;mobileUI=1&amp;mobileUI.theme=none&amp;mobileUI.titleBarOverlaid=1&amp;viewport_is1000px=1060"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron-1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/5grid/core.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/5grid/core-desktop.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/5grid/core-1200px.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/5grid/core-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->

    <!-- Photo gallery stuff -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slideshow/slideshow.css">
    <style>
        .slideshow { margin-left: 24.45%; }
    </style>
    <script src="js/mootools-1.3.2-core.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mootools-1.3.2.1-more.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slideshow.js"></script>

    <script>
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        var data = { 'pic07.jpg': {/*No captions, thumbnails or anything*/}, 'pic06.jpg': {}, 'pic10.jpg': {}, 'pic02.jpg': {}};
        new Slideshow('slideshow', data, { controller: false, thumbnails: false, loader: false, height: 400, width: 600, hu: 'images/', transition: 'back:in:out'});
    });
</script>
    <!--End-->
</head>
<body class="homepage">
    <!-- Header Wrapper -->
        <div id="header-wrapper">
            <div class="5grid-layout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">

                        <!-- Header -->
                            <section id="header">

                                <!-- Logo -->
                                    <img class="logo" src="images/aqua.jpg">

                                <!-- Nav -->
                                    <nav id="nav" class="mobileUI-site-nav">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </nav>
                            </section>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <!-- Banner -->
                            <section id="banner">
                                <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
                            </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">

                            <!-- Intro -->
                            <section id="intro">
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <a href="#" class="button button-big">Get Started</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="button button-alt button-big">Learn More</a>
                                </div>

                            </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Footer Wrapper -->
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
            <!-- Footer -->
                <section id="footer" class="5grid-layout">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="4u">
                            <section>
                                <header>
                                    <h2>Links</h2>
                                </header>
                                <ul class="divided">
                                    <li><a href="events.php">Events/Tickets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="4u">

                            <section>
                                <header>
                                    <h2>Connect with us</h2>
                                </header>
                                <ul class="social">
                                    <li class="facebook"><a href="#" class="icon48 icon48-1">Facebook</a></li>
                                    <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/n33co" class="icon48 icon48-2">Twitter</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="contact">
                                    <li>
                                        <h3>Address</h3>
                                        <p>
                                            Aqua, LLC<br />
                                            39 Old Ridgebury Road<br />
                                            Danbury, CT 06810
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <h3>Phone</h3>
                                        <p>(800) 000-0000</p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="12u">

                            <!-- Copyright -->
                                <div id="copyright">
                                    <ul class="links">
                                        <li>&copy; Aqua, LLC</li>
                                        <li>Images: <a href="http://facebook.com/DreametryDoodle">Dreametry Doodle</a> + <a href="http://iconify.it">Iconify.it</a></li>
                                        <li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 Up!</a> + <a href="http://daytaro.com">Daytaro</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's repeated really awkwardly after that.  It might the FTP server, I use [Koding](https://koding.com/) (don't ask) for this and it's connected to my server via FTP.  I tried using FileZilla too (didn't delete files before re-uploading) but that didn't do anything.

Comment: are you uploading the file without deleting it first?Some ftp clients will write over with some extra code

Comment: Ther you go! Might be the FTP client like I said on the edit

Comment: give it a try and that doesnt work, then update your question since it wont be FTP related

Comment: Woohoo! That did it! Too bad I spent an entire day trying to solve that.....sigh
How should I update my question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you delete the file before uploading it. Some FTP clients will write over with some extra code...

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks, I guess [Koding](http://example.com)'s upload method was causing issues